# Having trouble with directlabels 'last.bumpup'

Tags: ggplot2, direct-labels

I've used this positioning method in the directlabels package for years, and it was working successfully not even 3-4 months ago. However, I keep getting the same error message. Any suggestions? I find this method looks much neater than ggrepel, though I haven't worked with that package very much.

```
geom_dl(aes(label=Var1),method=list("last.bumpup",cex=0.8))
```

Error in get(method[[1]]) : object 'last.bumpup' not found

Comment: Ended up finding a solution. geom_dl(aes(label=Var1),method=list("last.points","bumpup",cex=0.8))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.